# Angular7: Showing data on pie chart tool tip rather than hover on it using MDBootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular7, mdbootstrap

I made a pie chart using MDBootstrap material design, the data showing on a pie chart is only on hover like this [on-hover-only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cflgO.png)  but I need to show data on its section or tooltip like this [bar-with label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bMPS.png) I'm using angular 7 and below is my code, please check

HERE is my **barchart.component.ts** file

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-barchart',
  templateUrl: './barchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./barchart.component.css']
})
export class BarchartComponent implements OnInit {
  public chartType: string = 'pie';

  public chartDatasets: Array<any> = [
    { data: [300, 50, 100, 40, 120], label: 'My First dataset' }
  ];

  public chartLabels: Array<any> = ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Grey', 'Dark Grey'];

  public chartColors: Array<any> = [
    {
      backgroundColor: ['#F7464A', '#46BFBD', '#FDB45C', '#949FB1', '#4D5360'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['#FF5A5E', '#5AD3D1', '#FFC870', '#A8B3C5', '#616774'],
      borderWidth: 2,
    }
  ];

  public chartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true
  };
  public chartClicked(e: any): void { }
  public chartHovered(e: any): void { }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and **HTML** FILE:

```
 <div style="display: block; width: 30%;">
  <canvas mdbChart
      [chartType]="chartType"
      [datasets]="chartDatasets"
      [labels]="chartLabels"
      [colors]="chartColors"
      [options]="chartOptions"
      [legend]="true"
      (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
      (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Hi Hille thanks for your response but sorry to say I already shared my code which I tried and attached a picture what I want to do or achieve I only need labels on my pie chart, I will appreciate if you could help me!

Comment: chart.js options work on mdbootstrap... go to https://www.chartjs.org for the options that you're looking for

Comment: is there any other option withour chart.js without any dependencies